# Simple jquery script not working in chrome. Disallowed characters?

Tags: jquery

I have a little script that is used to detect the URL a current user is on, and display a bit of content if the URL conditions are met.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {
    if (location.pathname == "/ProductDetails.asp" || location.pathname.indexOf("-p/") != -1) {
        var content = "<div class='ad-bar'><ul><li class='ad-bar-ship'><a href='/shipping-info_a/57.htm' target='_blank'><span>FREE SHIPPING!</span><br />on your order over $39</a></li><li class='ad-bar-price'><a href='/price-match-guarantee_a/289.htm' target='_blank'><span>SEEN A LOWER PRICE?</span><br />let us know here, and we'll beat it!</a></li><li class='ad-bar-coupon'><a href='/find-me-a-coupon_a/290.htm' target='_blank'><span>COUPON HUNTING?</span><br />let us find one for you!</a></li></ul></div>";

        var el = $('#v65-product-parent');

        // If there's an element with id = content_area in the page,
        // let's insert the content after it.
        // Otherwise, let's insert it to the body.
        if (el != null) {
            $(el).after(content);
        }
        else {
            $('body').append(content);
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

The script works fine in IE and Firefox, but not in chrome. I tried replacing the content I wish to display to a simple word, and it works. There is some element or character inside the content I wish to display that is not sitting well with Chrome.

I'm kind of a jquery noob. Is there a character within the content that I am not allowed to use? Will the single quote not work?

Thanks - Alex

Comment: Are you using a GreaseMonkey or UserScript?

Comment: I'm not sure man. Don't really know what the difference is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code didn't work for me in both Firefox and Chrome - but not because you are using incorrect code. **AdBlock** just blocks your DIVs because of it's classes `ad-bar`. So try turning off your adblocker and see if it works - if yes, you should rename your classes to not get caught by Adblock anymore.

Comment: That was it. I'll be sure to keep this in mind when choosing class names in the future. Thanks.